# How to stream multicast from pcap file (automation)

Tags: stream, udp, video-streaming, rtp, pcap

I have 3 pcap files - UDP, RTP and RTP with FEC. The last one means that I have 3 sockets that have to go at the same time for error correction.

I tried to use tcpreplay but it doesn't work if streamed inside of 1 machine which is the purpose.  Docker won't work because of the same problem, virtualization could work but the Linux kernel I'm working with makes a huge problem so I'm looking for another tool like tcpreplay that would stream to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bittwist uses the same lib under the hood as tcpreplay. The actual solution was:

```
sudo sysctl -a | grep "\.rp_filter" | awk '{print $1 "=0"}' | xargs sudo sysctl
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is bittwist. bittwist.sourceforge.net
It requires libpcap-devel module from linux repos. Stream to loopback intarface.
Still would be happy to get to know any other solutions.